# Can I force SQL Server to use a 2 digit int as primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am working on a question bank and each question will have a numerical serial number. My idea was to use each table's primary key and simply compound them into a new column in a view as required. But obviously, SQL Server will automatically start numbering int's at 1. I would like them to instead be 01, 02, 03...09, 10.

Is this even possible? Or is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do? I am using SQL Server 2014 Standard. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think is different between 01 and 1?

Comment: Why does this matter?  If you're trying to change the formatting it shows up as when you display it, that should be handled in either your `SELECT` statement or application layer, not your data layer.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to multipurpose your primary key field for better viewing.

Comment: The difference is in terms of serial number length.  I always want the serial numbers to be the same length, therefore, 01 is preferred to 1.

Comment: Are only going to allow 99 questions? Aside from the very valid arguments about why this is not a good idea if you limit it to 2 characters you can't have more than 99 questions.

Comment: Not 99 questions, but other fields, such as authors and certain categories will never expand past 99.  Our company has been in business for 20+ years and has never had more than 6 authors.  It also has to do with the fact that the coding system has already been in use and cannot be changed at this point without reprinting thousands of pages of information which is not cost effective.

Comment: You are speaking on format, IMHO. Database is not for formatting. Can you "move" the format logic into the application layers? Thus, you can keep your numerical datatype as is, changing them into the app layers. Additionally, you move also the biz logic out of database, decoupling it from the apps.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a presentation issue.  I would suggest adding a computed column to zero pad.  Here is one way:

```
alter table add questionid as (right(cast(10000 + id as varchar(255)), 2))
```

Then you can have an identity id and a zero padded version for output purposes.

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't thought of that...that's exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. What you could do is create a Sql View that returns the id formatted as a varchar(2) and append a 0 to the id if it is less than 10. Alternatively you can use a varchar(2) as the primary identifier but you would have to manually create the id at creation time.

Comment: a) I think char(2) more clearly expresses the OP's intent. b) When you append '0' to '1', you get '10'. To get '01' instead you *prepend* '0' to '1'. (My daughter gave me Word-of-the-day toilet paper for Christmas.)